# how to use ionic 2 native file plugin

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to use ionic's File native plugin but don't know how. 
Here's my code:

```
var path = fileURI.substr(0, imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var name = fileURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
File.readAsDataURL(path, name)
              .then(function (base64) {
                  console.log(base64);
              })
```

When I ran the code, I got a TypeError which contains an undefined message. What is the correct way to use the file plugin?

Comment: I too am struggling with this. Did you find a solution?